# Conflicting Task<ReviewInfo> class, google service gms vs core

Tags: android, google-play-services

I encountered this error while building my app after adding in app review feature. Other similar problems seems to advise on correcting the dependencies version but both gms and core seems to be on the latest (no warning sign on android studio). What direction should I go in order to fix this problem?

```
error: incompatible types: com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<ReviewInfo> cannot be converted to com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task<ReviewInfo>
```

Snippet of my gradle file

```
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'
    implementation "com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3"
    implementation("com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0")
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:3.0.2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.
Per https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore, I removed the core dependency ("com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3") and update any existing import statements of Task objects from import com.google.android.play.core.tasks.*; to import com.google.android.gms.tasks.*;